# Codeigniter - Creating own helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to create my own helper.
First i create a file called HelperModelBase.

This is a abstract class.

```
abstract class Pasaj_Model_Base {

    public $table_name;
    public $table_alias;
    public $class_name;
    public $lastSql;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->class_name = get_class($this);
        $this->table_name = strtolower($this->class_name);
        $this->table_name = str_replace('_dbview', '', $this->table_name);
    }
```

and create a method called select

```
public function select($where = null, $order = null, $limit = null, $columns = '*') {
        if (!$columns)
            $this->db->select('*');
        elseif (is_array($columns)) {
            $columns = implode(',', $columns);
            $this->db->select($columns);
        }



}
```

As you see above i do a simple select operation but , What i want to do  is that i add one or more operation.

For example where and order by in order to do that. I add this to my method:

```
if($where)
```

Problem begins here because codeigniter has a special code to handle where operations.

```
$this->db->where();
```

how can i do that ? How can i that where situtation to my

```
$this->db->select();
```

Thank you .

Finally i come to this.

```
public function select($where = null, $order = null, $limit = null, $columns = '*') {
        if (!$columns)
            $this->db->select('*');
        elseif (is_array($columns)) {
            $columns = implode(',', $columns);
            $this->db->select($columns);
        }

        if($where) 
            $this->db->where($where);
        if($order)
            $this->db->order_by($order);
        if($limit)
            $this->db->limit($limit);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query;
    }
```

i will notice about syntax of parameters . Can above code run ?

Comment: Usually your calls to the database are in the models, not in the helpers. Moreover, what is contained in your where when it's not null ?

Comment: Move your queries to model, and create methods which will manipulate those datas.

Comment: i know this is meaningless but unfortunately my boss wants like that :@

Comment: How about creating different methods depending on presence of where, order by clause? Then, in the controller class, put conditionals and call the appropriate method from the helper in the controller? Sounds ugly but it may help you.

Comment: Did your boss explicitly say "make me an abstract class overriding the db driver inside an HELPER or you're fired", or you could trick into making this class but where it should fit best?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have a look at

[CodeIgniter User Guide : Models](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

With CodeIgniter, the calls to the databases are made in the models, not in the helpers.

Then, if your `$where` is an associative array (in fact if I read your code well it have to), you can do a `foreach` loop to assign `where` clauses and values.