# Creating helpers -> Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to create my own helper but face a problem.

First i create a function called select. First if you see something wrong in this method pls tell me.

```
public function select($where = null, $order = null, $limit = null, $columns = '*') {
        if (!$columns)
            $this->db->select('*');
        elseif (is_array($columns)) {
            $columns = implode(',', $columns);
            $this->db->select($columns);
        }

        if ($where)
            $this->db->where($where);
        if ($order)
            $this->db->order_by($order);
        if ($limit)
            $this->db->limit($limit);

        $query  = $this->db->get('pasaj_register');

        return $query;
    }
```

and then i try to call this function like that

```
pasajItem  = new pasajItem();
         $a = $pasajItem->select();
         echo $a;
```

However i take this error:
[image]

Comment: As told you in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580454/codeigniter-creating-own-helper), DB should go into the MODEL. WHY does this really need to be into an helper? why not a library? a model? a driver? Anyway, HELPERS are NOT CLASSES. For this question and other Qs of yours I saw before, I suggest you take a small break and start reading the (great) CI's documentation; many of your question would be avoided/answered just by having a general better understanding of how CI works. CI's one of the best documented framework out there, take advantage of this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a helper you cannot acces the database.
First of all, it's not intended to do so.
You'll probably want to make a library of this, where you give a reference to the database on creation.

Besides the design flaw i believe you are making here, you have to use:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->db->*****
```

to access the CodeIgniter Database from a helper or library.
This is because they don't derive form a CodeIgniter standard class which contains the objects.